# C# Process bitmap pixel via pointers

Tags: c#, pointers, memory, bitmap

I'm trying to compare 2 bytes arrays which holds the `RGBA` values of 2 `32bpp` images(1920X1080 in my case), and to do some operation on their bits(not really relevant to the question).

I compare 4 bytes at once,using  a `int` pointer to the first desired pixel.

This is my code:

```
private unsafe void Process(byte[] prev, byte[] curr, Rectangle rect)
{

fixed (byte* image1BasePtr = prev, image2BasePtr = curr)
{
    int offset = (rect.Y * mainBmp.Width) + rect.X;

    int* prevPtr = (int*)image1BasePtr;
    prevPtr += offset;
    int* currPtr = (int*)image2BasePtr;
    currPtr += offset;

    int toY = rect.Y + rect.Height;
    int toX = rect.X + rect.Width;
    for (int y = rect.Y; y < toY; y++)
    {

        for (int x = rect.X; x < toX; x++)
        {

            if (currPtr[x] != prevPtr[x]) // Compare 4 bytes at once.
            {
                //Here i do somthing..doesn't really matter what

            }

        }
        prevPtr += mainBmp.Width; // Advance pointers to the next line.
        currPtr += mainBmp.Width;// Advance pointers to the next line.

    }
  }
}
```

I can choose an specific area to process, if i don't want to process the entire image.

This is the call(for example):

```
Process(rgbprev, rgbcurr, new Rectangle(1000, 0, 920, 1080));
```

In this case,the scan will start from the 1000's pixel,to the end of the bitmap(1920 in my case),and from the first line (`Y=0` ) to the last one.

When I run the code I get and exception on  `y=1079 and x=1630` :

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I think something with my pointers logic is wrong.... but cant find what.

Does anyone see the problem here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is just your `+ rect.X` in your first offset.

As you're starting from rect.X in your second for loop, you don't have to add it the first time.

Comment: i also thought so... but when i remove the `rect.X` in the offset...  the `if` condition never get's true,(and **there are** few different pixels in the images  which i see in my eye)....